# Using SSIS to upload data from Box.com to SQL

Tags: ssis

The company we are working with is uploading their data to box.com.  Our role is to move this data from box.com to sql. We eventually will use Tableau or Power BI to analyze their data.  However, I am still waiting to gain access to box.com through my company. I have never worked with box.com.  Does anyone have any guidance or suggestions about how to connect to box.com using SSIS.  Any tips, tricks, pitfalls to be aware of.

I spent time googling this but I don't see much information out there.

Comment: https://www.kingswaysoft.com/solutions/ssis-cloud-storage-components/box-data-integration

Comment: Thanks Amira.  Our company is strict about using third-party software.  Will I need to purchase this software just to grab data from box.com?   Hoping there are alternative options out there.